# Index Match from different tables - Excel

Tags: excel, match

I'm trying to check in a big table if all the issuer group codes correspond to the right group. To do this check I have an auxiliary table where I have all the possible Issuer Groups with the correspondent Issuer Group Code.

This are my tables:

[image]

and the formula I am using is:

```
=IF(S2994=0;IF(+INDEX($AQ$6:$AQ$6235;MATCH(AP2994;$AP$6:$AP$6235;0))=INDEX('Issuer e LEI'!$D$3:$D$90;MATCH(AP2994;'Issuer e LEI'!$C$3:$C$90;0));0;1);0)
```

But as you can see for example ABERTIS INFRAESTRUCTURAS, S.A. is right but I still get the 1.

Comment: Are there any trailing spaces in either of the cells containing 'ABERTIS INFRAESTRUCTURAS, S.A.'?

Comment: No. The name is a copy paste value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this formula be easier to work with?

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(AP2994,'Issuer e LEI'!$C$3:$D$900,2,FALSE)=AQ2994, 0, 1)
```

Basically, looks up the value in AP2994 in the table on the next tab, returns the code in the second column, and compares it to the value in column AQ.  If they are the same, it returns 0, and if they are different, it returns 1.

Comment: Thanks, I complicated it too much :)